# how to breed te fallen angel dragon

Tags: dragon-city

Anyone of you may you please tell me how to breed the fallen angel dragon. It is a really hard dragon to breed and I would appreciate some supportive comments down below in the comments section. thank you very much! I have tried venom and sun so many times and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could breed one by using any two-elemental dragon that has dark plus a archangel dragon, or by using any two-elemental dragon that has archangel plus a dark dragon, but there is a chance that you will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Try breeding a Dark Fire Dragon and a Sun Dragon.